# androidannotations can not find variables

Tags: android, android-annotations

I tried use androidannotations library and i have some problems. After run app when i click button open activity i see this error:

```
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{driverclient.sedi.ru.driverclient/sedi.driverclient.activities.balance_activity.BalanceHistoryActivity_}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View$OnFocusChangeListener)' on a null object reference
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2376)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1281)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setOnFocusChangeListener(android.view.View$OnFocusChangeListener)' on a null object reference
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at sedi.driverclient.activities.balance_activity.BalanceHistoryActivity.initUiElements(BalanceHistoryActivity.java:87)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at sedi.driverclient.activities.balance_activity.BalanceHistoryActivity.onCreate(BalanceHistoryActivity.java:72)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at sedi.driverclient.activities.balance_activity.BalanceHistoryActivity_.onCreate(BalanceHistoryActivity_.java:40)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5975)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
09-11 15:42:15.376  12443-12443/? W/System.err﹕ at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2269)
```

I do all by documentation. It is my Activity:

```
@EActivity(R.layout.activity_balance_history)
public class BalanceHistoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnFocusChangeListener {

    @ViewById(R.id.sbh_etStartDate)
    EditText etStartDate;

    @ViewById(R.id.sbh_etFinishDate)
    EditText etFinishDate;

    @ViewById(R.id.sbh_spnrOperationType)
    Spinner spnrOperationType;

    @ViewById(R.id.sbh_btnGetHistory)
    Button btnGetHistory;

    @ViewById(R.id.sbh_btnClose)
    Button btnClose;

    @ViewById(R.id.sbh_lvHistoryList)
    ListView lvHistoryList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        MessageBox.setFormContext(this);
        ProgressDialogHelper.SetFormContext(this);

        setTitleInfo();
        initUiElements();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        MessageBox.setFormContext(this);
        ProgressDialogHelper.SetFormContext(this);
    }

    /**
     * Инициализация UI элементов
     */
    @AfterViews
    public void initUiElements() {
        etStartDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        etStartDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        etFinishDate.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        etFinishDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnGetHistory.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnClose.setOnClickListener(this);
        initDataForUiElements();
    }

    /**
     * Инициализаия данных в UI элементах
     */
    @AfterViews
    public void initDataForUiElements() {

        String[] operationType = {AppContext.getInstance().getString(R.string.AllOperation),
                AppContext.getInstance().getString(R.string.WriteIn),
                AppContext.getInstance().getString(R.string.WriteOff)};

        etStartDate.setText(DateTime.Now().GetDateString());
        etFinishDate.setText(DateTime.Now().GetDateString());
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, operationType);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spnrOperationType.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    /**
     * Установка информации в ActionBar
     */
    @AfterViews
    public void setTitleInfo() {
        ActionBar supportActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (supportActionBar != null) {
            supportActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            supportActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
            supportActionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_white_edit_property);
            supportActionBar.setTitle(getString(R.string.AccountHistory));
        }
    }

    public void updateTitleInfoWithBack(int icon, int title) {

    }

    /**
     * Показать диалог для выбора даты;
     *
     * @param editText поле для установки значения после выбора;
     */
    private void showDatePickerDialog(final EditText editText) {
        try {
            DateTime dateTime;

            if (editText.getText().toString().length() < 1)
                dateTime = DateTime.Now();
            else {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
                Date date = sdf.parse(editText.getText().toString());
                dateTime = new DateTime(date);
            }

            int day = dateTime.GetDay();
            int month = dateTime.GetMonth() - 1;
            int year = dateTime.GetYear();

            final DateTime date = new DateTime();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
            final View datePicker = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_datepicker, null);
            final DatePicker picker = (DatePicker) datePicker.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
            picker.init(year, month, day, null);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BalanceHistoryActivity.this).setTitle(getString(R.string.SelectDate)).setView(datePicker);
            builder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.Ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    date.SetYear(picker.getYear());
                    date.SetMonth(picker.getMonth());
                    date.SetDay(picker.getDayOfMonth());
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            editText.setText(date.GetDateString());
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            builder.create().show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ToastHelper.ShowError(304, e.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home: {
                finish();
                return true;
            }
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.sbh_etStartDate:
            case R.id.sbh_etFinishDate: {
                showDatePickerDialog((EditText) v);
                break;
            }
            case R.id.sbh_btnClose: {
                BalanceHistoryActivity.this.finish();
                break;
            }
            case R.id.sbh_btnGetHistory: {
                if (validDateRange()) break;
                break;
            }
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    private boolean validDateRange() {

        if (etStartDate.getText().length() < 10 || etFinishDate.getText().length() < 10) {
            MessageBox.show(getString(R.string.IncorrectStartEndDate), null);
            return false;
        }

        final DateTime startDate = DateTime.getDateFromString(etStartDate.getText().toString());
        if (startDate == null) {
            ToastHelper.ShowError(305, "null");
            return false;
        }
        startDate.SetHour(0);
        startDate.SetMinute(0);

        final DateTime finishDate = DateTime.getDateFromString(etFinishDate.getText().toString());
        if (finishDate == null) {
            ToastHelper.ShowError(306, "null");
            return false;
        }
        finishDate.SetHour(23);
        finishDate.SetMinute(59);

        try {
            long a = Long.parseLong("3456000000");
            if (Math.abs(finishDate.GetTime() - startDate.GetTime()) > a)
                MessageBox.show(getString(R.string.MaxDayDiapason), null);
            else {
//                AsyncAction.run(new IFunc<Object>() {
//                    @Override
//                    public Object Func() throws Exception {
//                        getDriverHistory(startDate, finishDate);
//                        return null;
//                    }
//                });
                getDriverHistory(startDate, finishDate);
            }
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Получение истории счета водителя за промежуток времени
     *
     * @param startDate  дата начала
     * @param finishDate дата конца
     */
    private void getDriverHistory(DateTime startDate, DateTime finishDate) {
        try {
            ProgressDialogHelper.Show();

            ServerProxy.GetInstance().GetBalanceHistories2(startDate, finishDate, spnrOperationType.getSelectedItemPosition(), new IRemoteCallback<DriverBalanceHistory2[]>() {
                @Override
                public void Callback(Exception ex, DriverBalanceHistory2[] result) throws Exception {
                    ProgressDialogHelper.Hide();
                    if (ex != null) {
                        LogUtil.log(LogUtil.ERROR, ex.getMessage());
                        return;
                    }

                    List<String> strHistory = new ArrayList<String>();
                    for (DriverBalanceHistory2 history : result) {
                        strHistory.add(String.format("%s %s %dр. %s(%s)", new DateTime(history.OperationDateTime).GetDateTimeString(),
                                (history.Transfer ? getString(R.string.DoWriteOnBalance) : getString(R.string.DoWriteoffOnBalance)),
                                Math.abs(history.TransferSum),
                                (history.Detail.length() > 1 ? "за  " + history.Detail.toLowerCase() : ""),
                                String.format(getString(R.string.BalaceBeforAfterFormat), history.BalanceBefore, history.BalanceAfter)));
                    }
                    lvHistoryList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(BalanceHistoryActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, strHistory));
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogUtil.log(LogUtil.ERROR, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if (hasFocus && v instanceof EditText)
            showDatePickerDialog((EditText) v);
    }
}
```

In the manifest i change `BalanceHistoryActivity_`

I write all annotations. 
Aftwr compile i have this

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        OnViewChangedNotifier previousNotifier = OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(onViewChangedNotifier_);
        init_(savedInstanceState);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        OnViewChangedNotifier.replaceNotifier(previousNotifier);
        setContentView(layout.activity_balance_history);
    }
```

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="10dp" android:id="@+id/sbh_llContent">

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/With_"
                    android:id="@+id/sbh_tvStartDateCaption" android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize_18"/>
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/sbh_etStartDate" android:hint="Начальная дата"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.5">
            <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@string/To_"
                      android:id="@+id/sbh_tvFinishDateCaption" android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize_18"/>
            <EditText
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:inputType="date"
                    android:ems="10"
                    android:id="@+id/sbh_etFinishDate" android:hint="Конечная дата"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/Operation_"
                android:id="@+id/textView3" android:textSize="@dimen/TextSize_18"/>
        <Spinner
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/sbh_spnrOperationType" android:minHeight="60dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/GetHistory"
                android:id="@+id/sbh_btnGetHistory" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@drawable/btn_green"
                android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
        <Button
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/Close"
                android:id="@+id/sbh_btnClose" android:layout_weight="0.5" android:background="@drawable/btn_lite_red"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" android:textColor="#ffffffff"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/sbh_lvHistoryList" android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please show your `activity_balance_history.xml` layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove

```
    setTitleInfo();
    initUiElements();
```

from your `onCreate` method. These methods are annotated using `@AfterViews`, so there is no reason to put it there, where view binds are not done yet in class generated by AndroidAnnotations.

Comment: I have 2 methods. How compilator understand what method to call first?

Comment: I don't use AA anymore, but I remember that the safest way was to add second method execution at the end of method, which you want to execute as first, which is annotated with `@AfterViews`.

Comment: why you do not use it anymore?

Comment: I need only @Background annotation. Mybe exist another libraries ehit this functionality?

Comment: For binding views, listeners etc. `ButterKnife` is enough. I don't see reason to use whole `AndroidAnnotations` for only `@Background`. For Asynctask you can read about `RoboSpice`, it gives very powerful options, which can help you in unexpected situations :)

Comment: ButterKnife  slows down the application. No?

Comment: "I have 2 methods. How compilator understand what method to call first?" AA cannot figure that out. The most safest is to just annotate one method with `@AfterViews`, then just simply call your methods from that. See [this](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/%40AfterXXX-call-order).